# SizedBox() error "Too many positional arguments: 2 expected, but 4 found. Try removing the extra arguments." flutter

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBNAf.png)[this is the SizedBox() issue I am seeing please help, the error says "Too many positional arguments: 2 expected, but 4 found. Try removing the extra arguments.'"][2]

Comment: Please add relevant code with your question.

Comment: add your code and also i can't see what your size.height is about, you don't have to add the entire code just the relevant part

Comment: sorry about that, please try now.

Comment: That's not actually a `SizedBox` error.  You didn't close the `Navigator.push` method call, so `SizedBox` is interpreted as its third positional parameter.

Comment: what is size.height? share it if u can. where is it declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Navigator.push()` is missing a parenthesis so add it at the end

```
Navigator.push(
   context,
   MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context){
     return Home();
    }
   ),
), // this is missing
```

Answer (score 1):

Close the parenthesis of `navigator.push` and `press` function

[image]